# Is there a way to shrink an Excel table to fit the data?

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have an Excel table that has several other places in the spreadsheet using for various reasons, and then I realized that the table had bad data.  I collected new data, and there were fewer rows in the new data set than in the previous table.

Is there a way I can simply shrink the table to reflect the new count of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at all sure I understand your requirement but I'm guessing you want to reduce the size of a Tables/Table without deleting entire rows in your spreadsheet (because of content present elsewhere in your spreadsheet in the same rows as your Table data).

If so, merely select the area of your table to be deleted and press <kbd>Delete</kbd>. If you want to remove the formatting that remains select the angle icon shown at the extreme bottom right of your Table and drag it up to suit.

I am assuming the (Table) rows to be deleted are a contiguous block at the bottom of the Table.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me.  I was trying to accomplish this without reordering the table (in order to get the empty rows at the bottom), without a mouse drag (the difference spans several screens), and preferably via VBA.   I think I just gave up and did the best I could back when I was working on this, but I greatly appreciate you trying to help.  I think while I typed this comment out I found a way to accomplish what it was I was working on, so thanks!